# Use VBA to change source file of chart pasted into PowerPoint using Link Data option

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation in which I create charts in Excel and then link them into the PowerPoint. There are two ways to do this:

1. Paste Special > Paste Link > Microsoft Excel Chart Object
2. Paste > Keep Source Formatting and Link Data / Use Destination Theme and Link Data

I would late like to use VBA to change the source Excel file. To do this, consider the following code:

```
Private Sub PrintLinks()
    Dim pptPresentation As Presentation
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim pptShape As Shape
    
    Set pptPresentation = ActivePresentation
    For Each pptSlide In pptPresentation.Slides
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
            If pptShape.Type = msoChart Or pptShape.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Or pptShape.Type = msoLinkedChart Then
                Debug.Print pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = "PATH/TO/NEW/FILE"
                pptShape.LinkFormat.Update
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This will work for the Paste Link case, but not the Link Data case, in which case `pptShape.Type = msoChart`. My question is if there is a way to make it work with Link Data as well. Wtih Paste Link, the `SourceFullName` property will point to a specific chart object, like `filename1.xlsx!Chart 1`, and changing it to `filename2.xlsx!Chart 1` will work as expected. In contrast, under the Link Data option the `SourceFullName` property only points to `filename1.xlsx` and I cannot figure out how to see what chart object within the file it is pointing to. Regardless, if I change `SourceFullName` to `filename2.xlsx` no error will be thrown, but as far as I can tell the pointer is still to `filename1.xlsx`, as the chart doesn't change.

Comment: Is this an effort to update a linked chart while a slideshow is running? PowerPoint doesn't like to do that.

Comment: No, imagine a situation where you have a monthly packet of charts and each month you need to archive the old Excel and PPT file and create new copies, then link the new PPT to the new Excel.

Comment: got the same problem exactly - have you found a solution elsewhere?